# Does adding a new member variable to a class affects the binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class called AMFactory in a shared library. This shared library is used by many user applications. Now I want to add a new private member variable to my class. Does this break the binary compatibility? If it breaks then is there a hack for it. In my case I don't want the user applications to be recompiled. Snippet of my class [AMFactory] and its base class[Factory] below.

```
namespace CF {
class CF_EXPORT Factory {
 public:
 virtual ~Factory();

 virtual bool registerManager(const std::string &_interface,
                      const Id_t &_id) = 0;
 virtual bool unregisterManager(const std::string &_interface,
                      const Id_t &_id) = 0;
};
}
namespace CF {
namespace AM {
class AMFactory : public CF::Factory {
public:
CF_EXPORT static std::shared_ptr<AMFactory> get();

CF_EXPORT AMFactory();
CF_EXPORT virtual ~AMFactory();

CF_EXPORT bool registerManager(const std::string &_interface,
                      const Id_t &_id);
CF_EXPORT bool unregisterManager(const std::string &_interface,
                      const Id_t &_id);

private:
CF_EXPORT bool registerManager(std::shared_ptr<AMManager>);
CF_EXPORT bool unregisterManager(std::shared_ptr<AMManager>);

static std::shared_ptr<AMFactory> theFactory;
ServicesMap services_;
};
}
}
```

Comment: Of course it breaks binary compatibility. Whether or not it's `private` doesn't matter. A member is a member, and adding a member changes the size of the object, not to mention that outdated users will now be leaving the 'unknown member' uninitialised, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d : If I change my class to singleton does it still leaves the 'unknown member' uninitialised?

Comment: I don't see how making it a singleton would affect that, but then nor does it matter to the main question asked: you'd still be breaking ABI and introducing undefined behaviour to all calling code.

Comment: @underscore_d: If the object creation itself is happening through the static function of the same class then why will it leave  'unknown member' uninitialised? May be I am not getting clear picture here.

Comment: OK, I guess using a create method could resolve the uninitialised member, but that's the least of your worries when breaking ABI like this.

Comment: @underscore_d: Ok thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to add a new private member variable to my class. Does this break the binary compatibility?

The size of your class will change, thus yes, it will break binary compability.

> If it breaks then is there a hack for it. In my case I don't want the user applications to be recompiled.

Not a one I am aware of. That's (also) why we focus on design before starting implementing.